# How to use proxy with Robobrowser

Tags: python, django

I'm working with http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/readme.html, (a new python library based on the beautiful soup and request libraries) within django. My django app contains :

```
def index(request):    

    p=str(request.POST.get('p', False)) # p='https://www.yahoo.com/'

    pr="http://10.10.1.10:3128/"
    setProxy(pr)

    browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
    postedmessage = browser.open(p)
    return HttpResponse(postedmessage)
```

I would like to add a proxy to my code but can't find a reference in the docs on how to do this. Is it possible to do this?

EDIT:

following your recommendation I've changed the code to

```
    pr="http://10.10.1.10:3128/"
    setProxy(pr)
    browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
```

with:

```
def setProxy(pr):
    import os
    os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = pr
    return
```

I'm now getting:

```
Django Version: 1.6.4
Exception Type: LocationParseError
Exception Value:    
Failed to parse: Failed to parse: 10.10.1.10:3128
```

Any ideas on what to do next? I can't find a reference to this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since RoboBrowser uses the request library, you can try to set the proxies as mentioned in the [request docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) by setting the environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`.

Comment: Try using "10.10.1.10:3128" as proxy value or "http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/"

Comment: It turned out that I had a few additional charachters at the end of the proxy string. when I removed them it started working using  pr="http://10.10.1.10:3128/". Thanks very much for the help. - Bill

Answer (score 10):

After some recent API cleanup in RoboBrowser, there are now two relatively straightforward ways to control proxies. First, you can configure proxies in your requests session, and then pass that session to your browser. This will apply your proxies to all requests made through the browser.

```
from requests import Session
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

session = Session()
session.proxies = {'http': 'http://my.proxy.com/'}
browser = RoboBrowser(session=session)
```

Second, you can set proxies on a per-request basis. The `open`, `follow_link`, and `submit_form` methods of `RoboBrowser` now accept keyword arguments for `requests.Session.send`. For example:

```
browser.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', proxies={'http': 'http://your.proxy.com'})
```

Comment: I just realized that robobrowser is your project. Thank you for creating it! - Bill

Comment: BTW, if you have a second, I have a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067874/how-to-submit-a-form-with-a-get-action-using-robobrowser