# How to submit a form with a get action using Robobrowser

Tags: python, forms, robobrowser

I am using the robobrowser library, I have come across a form:

```
<form action="/results" id="search">
            <div class="s_ctr">
                <fieldset>
                    <label class="jaw" for="ln">Search by Name</label><input type="text" placeholder="Search by Name" autocomplete="off" value="" tabindex="1" name="ln" maxlength="255" class="name" id="ln" data-key="true"><span>near</span><label class="jaw" for="loc">Enter City, State</label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter City, State" autocomplete="off" value="" tabindex="2" name="loc" maxlength="255" class="location" id="loc" data-key="true">
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" value="Find Physician" class="orange-btn" tabindex="4" id="btn-submit">

            </div>
        </form>
```

My code:

```
search_form = browser.get_form(id='search')
search_form        
search_form.fields['1']= name
search_form.fields['2']= address
# # Submit the form
browser.submit_form(search_form)
browser
```

I get the following error and traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\r1\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\r1\mlist\ml1\views.py" in ph
  48.             p = getPhone(A.name,A.address)
File "C:\r1\mlist\ml1\views.py" in getPhone
  191.     browser.submit_form(search_form)
File "C:\r1\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\browser.py" in submit_form
  343.         payload = form.serialize(submit=submit)
File "C:\r1\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\forms\form.py" in serialize
  225.         return Payload.from_fields(include_fields)
File "C:\r1\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\forms\form.py" in from_fields
  118.             payload.add(field.serialize(), field.payload_key)    

Exception Type: AttributeError at /ph/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

Can this form be submitted with robobrowser?

Comment: There is not enough information here at all to help you; most of the form is missing. Can you also include the full traceback please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the way you're setting the values of the form fields. To change the value of a field, write to its `value` attribute:

```
form.fields['ln'].value = name
# Or, as a shortcut...
form['ln'].value = name
```

Instead of setting the values of the form fields, your example code actually replaces the fields with unicode objects. Running `form['ln'] = name` doesn't set the value of the `ln` field to `name`; it *deletes* the `ln` field and replaces it with the `name` string. Then, when the form attempts to serialize its contents, it tries to call the `serialize` method of each of its fields. But strings don't define that method, which leads to the traceback you encountered.

Comment: Thank you very much. BTW does robobrowser have any functionality to handle javascript or ajax in pages (or do you plan to introduce it)? - Bill